# RubyCAS-Client question: Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, url, plugins

I've installed RubyCAS-Client version 2.1.0 as a plugin within a rails app. It's working, but I'd like to remove the ?ticket= in the url. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

No. The ticket parameter needs to be there, because the RubyCAS client needs to get hold of these tickets somehow.
The URLs, that include these `ticket` parameters, are generated by the (Ruby)CAS server when you get redirected from there.

If the `ticket` parameter wasn't there, the whole CAS authentication wouldn't work.

Comment: Actually, if I remove the ticket parameter it still works, but it will put it back in the url when the new page olds. The older versions of RubyCAS Client didn't pass an id through the url... perhaps I'll stick with the old version... I'd rather have clean urls.